# How to get word vectors from pre-trained word2vec model downloaded from TFHub?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, word2vec

So I'm using the following word2vec model from TFHub:

```
embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/Wiki-words-250-with-normalization/2")
```

The type of this object is:

```
tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject
```

While I can use the model to embed lists of text, it's not clear to me how I can access the word embeddings themselves.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's discuss what is `embed` actually? According to the [official documentation](https://aihub.cloud.google.com/u/0/p/products%2Fda0a53b5-a301-4641-b41d-d8aec0db9753), the `embed` object is a TextEmbedding created based on Skipgram model stored in TensorFlow 2 format.

The Skipgram model is just a feed-forward neural network that takes the **one-hot encoding** representations of the words in the vocabulary as an input, and it *calculates* the word embedding. So, these word embeddings aren't stored within the model, they get calculated.

So, if you want the word embedding of separate words, then you can pass them one at a time like so:

```
# word embedding of `apple`
>>> apple_embedding = embed(["apple"])
>>> apple_embedding.shape
TensorShape([1, 250])

>>> #concatenation of three different word embeddings
>>> group = embed(["apple", "banana", "carrot"])
>>> group.shape
TensorShape([3, 250])
```

Comment: Yes you could do this, if you had a list of all the words. But that's a pretty silly thing to have to create on your own. So it turns out you can access the word embeddings from *embed* using *embed.embeddings*. The shape is (1009375, 250). That's 1M tokens! What I can't find is the actual dictionary that maps words to index in the embedding. That's really what I need.

Comment: Ok, I found a solution, although maybe not the optimal one. If you download the model archive from TFHub, there is a file in there called *tokens.txt* located in an *assets* folder. That file has 1009374 tokens, one per line. I am assuming the row number is the index of the token into the embeddings matrix. The only thing I don't know is whether the <oov> token is 0 in that index or the final entry, but that is something I can probably figure out pretty quickly.